# C# - How to map object structure to a TreeView?

Tags: c#, recursion, treeview

i would like to map the structure of an object to a TreeView. The object itself consists of `Dictionary<string,object>`. The problem for me now is that there is no consistency in how deep the structure can be because every `object` can be another dictionary (or just a text). For example, this is how one object could look like:
[image: One Object]

I know that i need some kind of recursion but i am not sure how i could map that to a tree view?
This is my current code:

```
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = (Dictionary<string, object>)e.Node.Tag; //dict is the object
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string,object> kvp in dict)
        {
            if(kvp.Key != "icon" && kvp.Key != "typeLine")
            {

            }
        }
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Edit: Sometimes the object of the KeyValuePair isn't another dictionary but just an array of objects (i dont't know why that is). It looks impossible, at least to me, to map that strange assembly of data to a treeview. Here is a picture about what i mean:

[image]

Edit(2): Okay, i think i finally got it working with this slightly modified function from Matthys:

```
        private TreeNode[] RecurseTree(Dictionary<string, object> dic)
    {
        List<TreeNode> branch = new List<TreeNode>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in dic)
        {
            TreeNode twig = new TreeNode(kvp.Key);
            if (kvp.Value is string || kvp.Value is bool || kvp.Value is int)
            {
                twig.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(kvp.Value.ToString()));
            }
            else if (kvp.Value is Dictionary<string, object>)
            {
                twig.Nodes.AddRange(RecurseTree((Dictionary<string, object>)kvp.Value));
            }
            else
            {
                IEnumerable enumerable = (kvp.Value as IEnumerable);
                if (enumerable != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in enumerable)
                    {
                        if (item is string || item is bool || item is int)
                        {
                            twig.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(item.ToString()));
                        }
                        else if (item is Dictionary<string, object>)
                        {
                            twig.Nodes.AddRange(RecurseTree((Dictionary<string, object>)item));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            IEnumerable en = (item as IEnumerable);
                            foreach(var i in en)
                                twig.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(i.ToString()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            branch.Add(twig);
        }

        return branch.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private TreeNode[] RecurseTree(Dictionary<string, object> dic)
{
    List<TreeNode> branch = new List<TreeNode>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in dic)
    {
        TreeNode twig = new TreeNode(kvp.Key);
        if (kvp.Value is string)
        {
            twig.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(kvp.Value.ToString()));
        }
        else if (kvp.Value is Dictionary<string, object>)
        {
            twig.Nodes.AddRange(RecurseTree((Dictionary<string, object>)kvp.Value));
        }
        else
        {
            IEnumerable enumerable = (kvp.Value as IEnumerable);
            if(enumerable != null)
            {
                foreach(var item in enumerable)
                {
                    if (item is string)
                    {
                        twig.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(item.ToString()));
                    }
                    else if (item is Dictionary<string,object>)
                    {
                        twig.Nodes.AddRange(RecurseTree((Dictionary<string, object>)item));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        branch.Add(twig);
    }

    return branch.ToArray();
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
 treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(RecurseTree(YourDictionaryObject));
```

I tested this code as follows:

```
        Dictionary<string, object> a = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> b = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> c = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> h = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> f = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> g = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> i = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        object[] arrayOfObjects = {"This","is","an","array","of","objects", i};

        object u, v, w, x, y, z;
        u = "string u";
        w = "string w";
        v = "string v";
        x = "string x";
        y = "string y";
        z = "string z";

        i.Add("i1",u);
        h.Add("h2", arrayOfObjects);
        h.Add("h1", y);
        d.Add("d2", h);
        d.Add("d1", x);
        c.Add("c1", w);
        b.Add("b1", c);
        b.Add("b2", v);
        b.Add("b3", d);
        a.Add("a1", b);
        a.Add("a2", z);

        treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(RecurseTree(a));
```

This is the result:

[image: TreeView]

Comment: Thanks alot, that solves a lot of my problems (but sadly not all of them). I added further details to my question. I would really appreciate it if you could take a look at it again.

Comment: I updated the answer, hope I understood you correctly. You may also want to add some sort of check to ensure that the object exposes a ToString() method so that it doesn't break when you come across an object that cannot be displayed as a string.

Comment: Edited the answer again, your array of object now also support objects that are Dictionary<string, object>.

Adding an array within the array is however not yet supported, but easy to add.

Comment: Okay, we are very close now but not fully there. But i don't know how i could describe it better, you already did a lot of work for me, thanks alot, i really appreciate it. Man, i hate the way that data is organized.

Comment: Provide some raw data? In what format do you have it?

Comment: JSON from the Path of Exile API: http://www.pathofexile.com/api/public-stash-tabs (takes a while to load). I use http://jsoneditoronline.org to look at the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121453/discussion-between-matthys-du-toit-and-binarybigint).

Comment: Okay, everything is working now i think. I fixed it with the code i appended to my initial question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, your problem is only insert a key and a value of a `KeyValuePair` in a `TreeView`. Does you want to add an item representing the key and containing the value? If it's so, here's the code to insert an item containing other items in a `TreeView`:

```
yourTreeView.Nodes.Add(kvp.Key);
yourTreeView.Nodes[yourTreeView.Nodes.Count - 1].Nodes.Add(kvp.Value);
```

**Edit:**

If so your problem is that `kvp.Value` isn't `string` but it's `object` you can use the `ToString()` method:

```
yourTreeView.Nodes.Add(kvp.Key);
yourTreeView.Nodes[yourTreeView.Nodes.Count - 1].Nodes.Add(kvp.Value.ToString());
```

If `ToString()` doesn't return a string with that's for you the correct formatting, you haven't got other choice than create your own method (better an extension method) to return the correct representation of your object:

```
public static class Extensions
{

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden]
    public static string AsString(this object obj)
    {
        return "Your correct string representation.";
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because `kvp.value` is not a string but an object.